# LCASE where search

Tags: php, mysql, lowercase

I'd like to search using the WHERE statement, but case-insensitive. I was told I could use `LCASE()`, but how would I do this with the following?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldt = '" .$_POST['thisf']. "'");
```

Comment: FYI: This code is not protected from SQL injection.

Comment: @Daniel: I am aware of that. This is simply an example.

Comment: You can set the column to be case insensitive so you don't have to do any of that lcaseing

Comment: @dqhendricks: My webhost said they disabled allowing case-insensitive but said I could use lcase.

Comment: never heard of that before. do you have phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trick it witht making both (field and needed data) in Upper/Lover case:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE UCASE(fieldt) Like UCASE('" .strtoupper($_POST['thisf']). "')");
```

Comment: @gdscei - `LIKE` makes it insensitive.

Comment: @gdscei now (I uppercase your post with php)?

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Though I did get out the UCASE() on the PHP variable, since that is not neccesary when you are already making the variable all upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I did not introduce a bunch of syntax errors:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE lcase(fieldt) = lcase('" .$_POST['thisf']. "')");
```

Comment: @gdscei:  What character set (and specific characters) are you testing?

Comment: latin1_swedish_ci, and no special characters but simple uppercase/lowercase letters and/or numbers.

Comment: @gdscei:  With that collation, the comparison should already be case insensitive (the _ci is supposed to represent that).  Can you provide a specific example that fails?

Comment: in the mysql table: `gdscei` and typed in a field: `Gdscei`. My webhost said they disabled allowing case-insensitive but said I could use lcase.

Comment: @gdscei:  That seems a bit puzzling.  I don't know of a reason why 'G' would not be converted to 'g' with that character set using lower()/lcase().  As a sanity check, does a search for 'gdscei' find that record in the table?

Comment: Would it maybe be easier to just set the "gdscei" to be lowercase before it is put in the table?

Comment: @gdscei:  It does not sound like you are successfully using the updated version of the php code.  If neither the UCASE or LCASE version (both should be equivalent) worked, then it sounds to me like the original query without those scalar functions is being run.

Comment: I am 100% sure that this query is being run. I tried lcase, ucase, = and like, none of which work.